# Use the power of the graphic card on a MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, graphics

Is there a way to use the processor of the graphic card on a new MacBook Pro to do some long and repetitive calculations?

Comment: Can you give some more details please?

Comment: This probably belongs on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at [CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home_new.html) (nVidia only) or [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) to do just this? Both technologies are made to leverage the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

Running computationally expensive tasks on the GPU is something that is coded on the development side.  This is not something an end user can do directly.  If this is something you intend to do from the development side, it should probably be posted on Stack Overflow.

[Wikipedia: GPGPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPGPU)

Comment: It was more on the end user side...

Comment: Just to be clear -- it is not possible from the end user side.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of programs written to use the GPU to help users run through various calculations more quickly than with their processor.

There is an OpenCL directory here of math programs claiming to use the GPU:

http://opencl.name/top/Science/Math/Software/

You'll have to sort through which ones run on OS X.

There are OpenCL tutorials on the net, though, and Xcode is inexpensive.  If you understand rudimentary programming principles you should be able to modify the examples/tutorials to do what you want.  When you get stuck, Stack Overflow is there to help.